# Restore-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem - The User input provided for the call is invalid

Tags: azure-powershell

I'm scripting a Powershell script, to restore a Backup item on a Recovery Vault Azure, from another recovery Vault.
Here is the main outline of the script (very refined version) :

```
#modules and variables
import-module Az

$Sub = "MyAzureSubscription"
$RsvSource = "MySourceRecoveryVault"
$RsvTarget = "MyTargetRecoveryVault"
$SubContext = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$SourceDB = "SourceDB"
$TargetDB = "TargetDB"
$SQLTargetInstance = "instance"
$SQLTargetServer = "SQLServer"

#Get Backup item from Azure RSV
Connect-AzAccount -Identity -Subscription $Sub

Set-AzContext -subscription $SubContext

$SourceVault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault | Where-Object { $_.name -eq $RsvSource }
$TargetVault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault | Where-Object { $_.name -eq $RsvTarget }

Set-AzRecoveryServicesVaultContext -Vault $SourceVault

$BackupItem = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -BackupManagementType AzureWorkload -WorkloadType MSSQL -VaultId $SourceVault.ID | Where-Object { ($_.Name -match $SourceDB ) }
#Get Point in time
$PointInTime = Get-Date -Date "12/1/2023" -format MM/dd/yyyy
#Get Parameters
$Container = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupContainer -ContainerType AzureVMAppContainer -VaultId $($TargetVault.id) | Where-Object {$_.ServerName -eq "$SQLTargetServer" -and $_.HealthStatus -eq 'Healthy'}

$TargetInstance = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupProtectableItem -WorkloadType MSSQL -ItemType SQLInstance -ServerName "$SQLTargetServer" -VaultId $($TargetVault.id)

$PointBackup = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupRecoveryPoint  -Item $BackupItem | Where-object { $_.RecoveryPointTime -match $PointInTime }


# Configuration
$AnotherInstanceWithFullConfig = Get-AzRecoveryServicesBackupWorkloadRecoveryConfig -PointInTime $($PointBackup.RecoveryPointTime) -Item $BackupItem -TargetItem $SQLTargetInstance -Targetcontainer $Container -AlternateWorkloadRestore -VaultId $($SourceVault.ID)
$AnotherInstanceWithFullConfig.OverwriteWLIfpresent = "yes"
$AnotherInstanceWithFullConfig.RestoredDBName = $TargetDB


$AnotherInstanceWithFullConfig.targetPhysicalPath[0].TargetPath = ($AnotherInstanceWithFullConfig.targetPhysicalPath[0].TargetPath) -replace (($AnotherInstanceWithFullConfig.targetPhysicalPath[0].TargetPath | split-path -leaf), "$TargetDB).mdf")

$AnotherInstanceWithFullConfig.targetPhysicalPath[1].TargetPath = ($AnotherInstanceWithFullConfig.targetPhysicalPath[1].TargetPath) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace (($AnotherInstanceWithFullConfig.targetPhysicalPath[1].TargetPath | split-path -leaf), "$TargetDB.ldf") -replace "I:", "L:" }

#restore
$restore = Restore-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem -WLRecoveryConfig $AnotherInstanceWithFullConfig -VaultId $($TargetVault.id)
```

I have an issue, i don't know how to resolve it. (Ms Doc, Google, ChatGPT, found nothing)

> Restore-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem :  The User input provided for the call is invalid. Please check the required inputs

Maybe $AnotherInstanceWithFullConfig ?

If i launch :

```
$AnotherInstanceWithFullConfig | Format-list
```

Here is the result:

> 

TargetServer           : SQLServer.domain
TargetInstance         : instance
RestoredDBName         : TargetDB
TargetVirtualMachineId : /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/RSGXXXXXXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SQLServer
OverwriteWLIfpresent   : yes
NoRecoveryMode         : Disabled
targetPhysicalPath     : {Name_Data, Name_log}
ContainerId            : /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/RSGXXXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/RSVXXXXXXXXXX/backupFabrics/Azure/protectionContainers/vmappcontainer;compute;rsgxxxxxxxx;SQlserver
FullRP                 :
SourceResourceId       : /subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/RSGXXXXXXXXXXX/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SQLServer
RestoreRequestType     : Alternate WL Restore to diff item
RecoveryPoint          : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.RecoveryServices.Backup.Cmdlets.Models.AzureWorkloadRecoveryPoint
PointInTime            : 12/1/2023 12:04:51 PM
RecoveryMode           :
FilePath               :

> 

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

> Restore-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem - The User input provided for the call is invalid:

This is a temporary issue might occur when any of the data types passing to the `Restore-AzRecoveryServicesBackupItem`are not correct as expected. Check the configuration object `$AnotherInstanceWithFullConfig` again.

And also make sure that you are checking the output stored in each variable is retrieving the expected output in each step as shown below.

[image]

And also verify the values of`OverwriteWLIfpresent` and `NoRecoveryMode` in `$AnotherInstanceWithFullConfig`object accordingly to meet your requirement.

If still the issue persists, use `try catch` blocks to obtain more relevant error information.